# JQuery if content change add something between the different content

Tags: jquery

i am searching for a solution. There are some list elements of the same type. In the li Container is a span with an date input. I would like to add a clear:both div between each content changing li (in my case the date).

I try this but it doesn't work.

```
if (jQuery("#rs_events_details span b").html() == jQuery((this).next(".rs_event_details span b")).html()){
  return "hallo";
  } else {
  return "tschau";
  }
```

Comment: And what's your HTML? What would you like jQuery to do to change that HTML?

Answer (score 0):

try this
.clear{clear:both};

```
$('#rs_events_details span b').on('click',function(){
    $("#target_div").addClass('clear');//note: replace #target_div with your respective divs
});
```